# A windows service to communicate with server application

Tags: c#, windows-services

Here's the basic idea:

There is an app running on server, and it is connected to a SQL database.
On a client side computer, there is a windows service running, which periodically attempts to communicate with the app on the server.
The app then checks, using info from db, if there are any new items for this client service, and if there are, it sends links for download, which the service handles.

Now, my question is about the best way of communication between the app and the service in this scenario. I have read about MSMQ and NamedPipes, like in the article here:
[Link to codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/846586/Queuing-Windows-Services-work-items-using-MSMQ-and)

but I'm wondering if this is the best and most easy-to-understand way of doing this type of thing? I heard WCF is advanced level and this is my first project doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Despite "best practices" often being stated there really are only "good practices" and what is good is context dependent. Using MSMQ allows chronological decoupling but you'll need to manage the queues (will each client have its own inbound queue). In practice a simple HTTP get returning a body with a list of updates is going to be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WCF with named pipes, it's clear and very easy to use.
Check [this](http://omegacoder.com/?p=101) to more information about named pipes in WCF.

You should also try to know a little more about [WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896436/all-about-wcf-client) before you begin the coding.´

Good luck.

PS: Don't get scarred with "what you heard", I don't really think WCF is so advanced level as you may heard, you only need to understand the concepts that are bound with WCF, the syntax and maintenance of the code is very easy to understand after a few examples, give WCF a chance and it will make you're live so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

We're using MSMQ with transactions. The app would write a message to the que, and the service would listen to the same que and trigger a handler. Very simple and robust communication.